# VBA Code runs on one Computer but not on another

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some code to run when the Workbook is opened and it works flawlessly on my personal computer. However after sending the file to my laptop I get the "application-defined or object-defined error" message. I genuinely do not understand why this has happened or how I can solve this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'loads the combobox when book opened

    MenuGenerator.miscComboBox.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Names("MenuMiscellaneous").RefersToRange)
    MenuGenerator.soupCombobox.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Names("MenuSoups").RefersToRange)
    MenuGenerator.saladComboBox.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Names("MenuSalads").RefersToRange)
    MenuGenerator.meatComboBox.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Names("MenuMeat").RefersToRange)
    MenuGenerator.fishComboBox.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Names("MenuFish").RefersToRange)
    MenuGenerator.starchComboBox.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Names("MenuStarch").RefersToRange)
    MenuGenerator.veggieComboBox.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Names("MenuVegetable").RefersToRange)
    MenuGenerator.dessertComboBox.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Names("MenuDessert").RefersToRange)

End Sub
```

The code is set to load named ranges I created into the comboboxes.

Comment: When the file was sent, did it include the module/userform `MenuGenerator`?

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity. MenuGenerator is the Name of the Sheet and was included when I sent the file. I also double checked to see if the named ranges were still defined, which they were. I then tried to rewrite it as  `Worksheets("MenuGenerator").etc` @Toddleson

Comment: The error "application-defined or object-defined error" commonly shows up when an object is referenced in the code but is not found or doesn't exist. Are you able to identify which object is causing the error? It should be either `MenuGenerator`, one of the combo-boxes or one of the names. A simple test would be to do something like `Debug.Print (myObject Is Nothing)`

Comment: Thats the weird thing. They all seem to exist. and the Scope of the Named Ranges is set for the whole Workbook. Maybe I will find a way to rewrite it in a manner that will work @Toddleson

Comment: try copying the code to notepad, removing the code, closing and saving the workbook (no code [.xlsx]), reopen the workbook and pasting the code back in and resaving (.xlsm).  I've had code modules get corrupt before and exporting and importing them back in doesn't help.  you have completely recreate (or copy back in from notepad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a diagnostic message box to the code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, i As Integer
    Dim fn, arObj, arMenu, rng As Range, obj
    Dim msg As String
    
    Set fn = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("MenuGenerator")
    
    arObj = Array("misc", "soup", "salad", "meat", "fish", "starch", "veggie", "dessert")
    arMenu = Array("Miscellaneous", "Soups", "Salads", "Meat", _
                   "Fish", "Starch", "Vegetable", "Dessert")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 0 To UBound(arObj)
        Set rng = Nothing
        Set obj = Nothing
        msg = ""

        Set rng = wb.Names("Menu" & arMenu(i)).RefersToRange
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            msg = msg & vbLf & "Error with name range 'Menu" & arMenu(i) & "'"
        End If
            
        Set obj = ws.OLEObjects(arObj(i) & "ComboBox")
        If obj Is Nothing Then
            msg = msg & vbLf & "Error with '" & arObj(i) & "ComboBox" & "'"
        End If
        
        If msg = "" Then
            obj.Object.List = fn.Transpose(rng)
        Else
            MsgBox msg, vbExclamation
        End If
       
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub
```